# Why is this example using ASIO async_receive_from not "leaky"

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Basically:

```
  void start_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
      boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(
          new std::string(make_daytime_string()));

      socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
          boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

      start_receive();
    }
  }
```

from:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html

From what I understand `start_recive` registers `handle_recive`, then `handle_receive` when called if everything is ok calls `start_receive` again to be reregistered and that is repeated. 
Thing I dont understand isnt there a possibility that data may slip between call to handle_receive and the time handle_receive calls start_receive again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible, but not likely to occur for the `udp_server` example in non-saturated conditions.

Although Boost.Asio may not have any pending read operations on a socket, the operating system's network stack will queue received data in kernel memory.  Boost.Asio's asynchronous operations use a reactor to be notified when the network stack has data available for reading on a given socket.  Once this notification has been processed, Boost.Asio will initiate a read from the socket, causing data to be copied from the network stack's kernel memory into the provided user memory.

The kernel's network stack and sockets often have a configurable parameter that controls their maximum buffer size.  For example, the [`receive_buffer_size`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/receive_buffer_size.html) socket option, [Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985816), or [Linux `sysctl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732314/1053968). With this memory limitation and UDP not having a guarantee of delivery, the network stack may drop datagrams if datagrams are being consumed (read) at a slower rate than which they are produced (received).

Comment: ah, so udp msgs get queued on the socket, and when I register a handler it pops one datagram of the socket q and gives ito the handler? async in the name confused me, i thought it is when you have data on this socket call me, if nothing is registered let data drop

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Basically, yes.  [`async_*`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) functions are _initiating functions_, and initiate a non-blocking operation; they do not cause state change (i.e. socket can no longer receive data).  In the original code, the operation will read data into `recv_buffer_`, then use the result to invoke `udp_server::handle_receive()` handler with the appropriate `error` and `bytes_transferred` values.

Answer (score 1):

The `socket_` has a buffer which stores incoming data until read. In the constructor of `udp_server` in the example udp socket is initialized to listen on port 13.

The listener service is started in main, with the `io_service.run()` call (which doesn't normally return).